# What is an appropriate NER entity for names which are not "PERSON" in SpaCy

Tags: nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition, labeling

Looking into the default SpaCy NER (Named Entity Recognition) for names associated to divinities such as "God" or "Vishnu". Similarly, what about names attributed to AIs, Robots or Pets such as "Chappy" or "Bart".

What would be an appropriate NER label?
I can only see "Person" but it doesn't feel appropriate.

Here below reporting the NER from Spacy glossary https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/glossary.py

```
# Named Entity Recognition
# OntoNotes 5
# https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/docs/LDC2013T19/OntoNotes-Release-5.0.pdf
"PERSON": "People, including fictional",
"NORP": "Nationalities or religious or political groups",
"FACILITY": "Buildings, airports, highways, bridges, etc.",
"FAC": "Buildings, airports, highways, bridges, etc.",
"ORG": "Companies, agencies, institutions, etc.",
"GPE": "Countries, cities, states",
"LOC": "Non-GPE locations, mountain ranges, bodies of water",
"PRODUCT": "Objects, vehicles, foods, etc. (not services)",
"EVENT": "Named hurricanes, battles, wars, sports events, etc.",
"WORK_OF_ART": "Titles of books, songs, etc.",
"LAW": "Named documents made into laws.",
"LANGUAGE": "Any named language",
"DATE": "Absolute or relative dates or periods",
"TIME": "Times smaller than a day",
"PERCENT": 'Percentage, including "%"',
"MONEY": "Monetary values, including unit",
"QUANTITY": "Measurements, as of weight or distance",
"ORDINAL": '"first", "second", etc.',
"CARDINAL": "Numerals that do not fall under another type",
```